# Yii2 jwt: не могу разобраться с куками

Tags: reactjs, yii2, axios, jwt

Хочу использовать JWT авторизацию в своем проекте. Проект на реакте. Авторизацию делаю по этой инструкции - [yii2 jwt](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2568/jwt-authentication-tutorial)

Все работает, но когда хочу сделать обновление токена - получаю ошибку

```
No refresh token found
```

Как я понял, оно не может найти куки.

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в том, что я не верно указал параметр path при создании куки. Указал просто / и все заработало